# Slideshow compilation takes 10 minutes for 3 images

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264

I want to make a slideshow from images. The first image has 6932x4683 pixels, so I got an error `height not divisible by 2` and I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847674/ffmpeg-libx264-height-not-divisible-by-2). I understand that `libx264` is implicit in the output as `.mp4`, and that `libx264` needs an input image whose dimensions are divisible by 2. So I used the padding filter recommended there:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i slideshow.txt -vf "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" slideshow.mp4
```

The file `slideshow.txt` is:

```
file '03.jpeg'
duration 2.5
file '01.jpeg'
duration 2.5
file '02.jpeg'
duration 2.5
file '02.jpeg'
```

The command took 10 minutes to process these 3 images. When playing the result, it skipped the middle image.

I tried outputting to `slideshow.MOV` and without the filter, and it also throws the same error.   I tried outputting to `slideshow.MTS` and without the filter, it works but the result shows no images when I play it on VLC.

Why does the command and the implicit call to libx264 take so long, and how can I avoid using libx264?

Comment: You're rendering 7.5 seconds x 25 frames/sec = 188 whole frames of `6932x4683` resolution. That will take quite a bit of processing time.

Comment: Indeed, scaling down (with `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i slideshow.txt -vf "scale=-1:720,pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2" slideshow.mp4`) takes 2.7 seconds to output a `1065x720` file. A quick calculation would suggest that the original command would take `2.7*(6932/1065)*(4683/720)=114` seconds. Is that rule of thumb a reasonable way to estimate processing time?

Comment: As a first approximation, yes, but modern encoders have some steps like motion search to identify conserved pixels which may be proportional to surface area in a non-linear fashion.

Comment: Thanks! Can you move the comments to an answer?